# Reason to run Prometheus as statefulset when increasing replicas

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus

I was checking out Prometheus as monitoring tool for EKS. I used helm charts for deployment. We are following a stateless architecture. So we want to make the other applications stateless too to suit our setup.

I saw it written in the values file such that, if planning to increase number of prometheus-server replicas from 1 make it a statefulset.(Line 496 of reference link I have shared at end)

```
  ## Use a StatefulSet if replicaCount needs to be greater than 1 (see below)
  ##
  replicaCount: 1
```

What is it's relevance? How does it make a difference?

We are ingesting the metrics into AWS managed Prometheus and querying from there. So do we have to persist the volumes?

Reference:

- https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/values.yaml